# Cannot convert ... to expected argument type 'PFIdResultBlock?'

Tags: ios, heroku, parse-server

In an `iOS` app using `parse-server` (on Heroku/mLab), I am having the following issue with a cloud function.
Here is the relevant code:

```
    PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "myCloudFunction",
                         withParameters: ["lastTouch" : theLastTouchStamp]) {
                            (any: Any, error: Error) in
                            print("Now Inside Block (myCloudFunction)")
    }
```

Here is the error message I get from the compiler:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Any, Error) -> ()' to expected argument type 'PFIdResultBlock?'
```

I have browsed the net in search for some information, but eventhough I found a couple of related post; nothing led me to a solution.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the types from the closure:

```
PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "myCloudFunction", withParameters: ["lastTouch" : theLastTouchStamp]) {
    (value, error) in

    print("Now Inside Block (myCloudFunction)")
}
```